# Geographically Weighted Regression fails QGIS

Tags: qgis, regression

So I'm trying to run GWR on a dataset in QGIS.

**It starts and then I get these messages at the end:**

"Converting outputs
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dataProvider' See log for more details"

**Other error messages in the log that look relevant are:**

GDAL: Export Raster: could not initialize data objects

GDAL: Export Raster: could not initialize data objects
Error: Grid file could not be opened.
Error: executing tool [GDAL: Export Raster]

**Other possibly relevant details:**

Both of the variables are Integers

The dataset has ~9800 entries

Any ideas about what to try or ideas about why its failing?